# How to change a textbox backcolor using an if statement?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to block out the textbox if the user selects a specific value from the dropdown (combobox). I am trying to change the textbox backcolor based on the value in a specific combobox. I have created the code below and was able to get it to work, but it only works if I manually run the macro in vba. Can you please assist me with this problem. Thanks

```
Private Sub discqty_DropButtonClick()

lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
lngYellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
lngWhite = RGB(255, 255, 255)


If combobox1.Value = "NON-CONFORMANCE" Then
    Me.discqty.Value = ""
    Me.discqty.BackColor = lngBlack
End If

If combobox1.Value = "BOM CHANGE" Then
    Me.discqty.Value = ""
    Me.discqty.BackColor = lngBlack
End If


If combobox1.Value = "WOC" Then
    Me.discqty.Value = ""
    Me.discqty.BackColor = lngBlack
End If



If combobox1.Value = "LOST PART" Then
    Me.discqty.BackColor = lngWhite
End If

If combobox1.Value = "DAMAGE/DESTROYED" Then
    Me.discqty.BackColor = lngWhite
End If

If combobox1.Value = "QA/QC ISSUE" Then
    Me.discqty.BackColor = lngWhite
End If
```

Call netvalue

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to out the Color changing part into the `combobox1_Change()` Sub

Double-click the `ComboBox` and then paste this into the `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` Sub that comes up.

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

      If ComboBox1.Value = "NON-CONFORMANCE" Then
          Me.discqty.Value = ""
          Me.discqty.BackColor = lngBlack
      ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "BOM CHANGE" Then
          Me.discqty.Value = ""
          Me.discqty.BackColor = lngBlack
      ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "WOC" Then
          Me.discqty.Value = ""
          Me.discqty.BackColor = lngBlack
      ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "LOST PART" Then
          Me.discqty.BackColor = lngWhite
      ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "DAMAGE/DESTROYED" Then
          Me.discqty.BackColor = lngWhite
      ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "QA/QC ISSUE" Then
          Me.discqty.BackColor = lngWhite
      End If

 End Sub
```